# Как создать массив динамически в ходе работы программы?

Tags: c++

```
int n = 255;
int *point = new int[n];
```

Это все хорошо и понятно. А как создать **совсем** динамический массив?
Ну, типа,

```
int n=0,myvar;
char choice;
do{
cin >> myvar;
myArray[n] = myvar;
cout << "continue? y/n \n";
cin >> choice;
}while(choice == 'y');
```

то есть, даже на момент создания массива, мы еще не знаем его длины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте о [Векторах](http://www.google.com.ua/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%2B%2B+vector)

Собственно как я понимаю это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос :)

Comment: от подарка не убежишь(с) Пчелайн. Плюсик и галочку. Это ответ на мой вопрос, но ответ отрицательный: в привычном мне понимании динамических массивов тут нет. Это список... Жаль. В любом случае, его можно использовать.

Comment: kness Это не список, это именно массив, который контролирует размер оставшейся памяти и произвожящий реаллокацию только когда память закончилась.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно для практического применения, то конечно, как уже было написано, используйте vector. Если же для упражнения и обучения, то можно предложить следующую конструкцию. Можно сделать класс, в котором есть метод добавления. При вызове этого метода он выделяет память для самого создаваемого объекта (в широком смысле) при помощи new. Указатель на этот объект сохраняется в массиве указателей, создаваемый с помощью malloc(), а изменяется его размер с помощью realloc(). Можно при создании такого самодельного векторного класса зарезервировать определенный размер этого массива указателей, при заполнении увеличить.

P.S. Так стоит заморочиваться, если хотите сохранять объекты и прочие сложные типы данных. Если же нужно сохранять только простые стандартные типы, то проcто создаете массив с помощью malloc(), а изменяете размер realloc().

Comment: remalloc - нет такого. Бывает только realloc.

Comment: Да, точно, перепутал. Спасибо. Есть замечания по существу?

Comment: По поводу этого:

>P.S. Так стоит заморочиваться если хотите сохранять объекты и прочие сложные типы данных. Если же нужно сохранять только простые стандартные типы, то про создаете массив с помощью malloc(), а изменяете размер realloc().

 Так не стоит заморачиваться всегда. Для хранения сложных объектов лучше хранить указатели, а создавать объекты вручную отдельно от массива через new.

 Кстати, malloc и realloc не вызовет конструктора объекта. Нужно использовать либо new и delete, либо malloc+размещающий new и явный вызов деструктора+free.

Comment: Так и я о том же. Может, невнятно написал. Почитайте внимательнее.

Comment: Я имею в виду, то, что написано до P.S не нужно.

Comment: Так я и написал там, что объекты создаем с помощью new, а указатели храним в отдельном массиве, создаваемом malloc() и изменяемом realloc(), Но если планируется работать только в простыми типами, можно их сразу сохранять в массиве, созданном malloc()'ом и расширять-сужать его realloc().

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам нужна библиотека `vector` или что-то похожее.

Comment: Только vector - это не библиотека, а только часть стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: в C++ я подключаю  
     #include<vector>  
и записываю в него  
     vector<int>c; c.push_back(12);

Answer (score 0):

Если хорошо знать C++, то можно создать такой массив, который так добавляет элементы:

```
myArray[n] = myvar;
```

Этого можно добиться при помощи перегрузки operator[] так, чтобы он возвращал прокси-объект с перегруженным operator=. Но это скорее всего снизит производительность, и у такого массива будут недостатки. Например, если при записи ты вышел за пределы, то массив молча расширится вместо того, чтобы сообщить об ошибке (хотя вектор, по-моему, о них и не сообщает). Это будет только скрывать ошибку.
 Лучше всё-таки использовать vector'оподобный массив.